# App get rejected due to uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme

Tags: ios

My app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.
I need to open the general "Setting" not the my app settings.

"UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString": This code only opens my app settings but I need to open the general "Settings" screen. what can i do? Any solution for overcome this problem?

Comment: Short answer, you can't.

Comment: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString is the another solution but it opens only my app settings but i need to open general iphone settings screen.

Comment: As I said, you can't.  There is no supported method to do that and prefs:root is private API

Comment: Then Paul any other Public api to open the settings screen or any other options.

Comment: Because i need to open settings > privacy > Motion and Fitness > Fitness tracking and Health

Comment: All you can do is provide instructions in your app for the user.  You cannot open that settings screen directly from your app.

Comment: I tested one of the app "truecaller". This have an option like "Open settings". I clicked the button then it will redirected to the settings screen of iphone not open the truecaller app settings. How it works any idea!

Comment: They are probably using the prefs private URI scheme and didn't get pulled up by app review. Chances are next time they submit an update they will need to change it.